# Split url string in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, split, xslt-2.0

How do we split some string based on some character/separator in given url.

Given url like: **www.example.com/content/index.html**

Desired output like: **Index**

Code:

```
<span transId="gadget_{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="www.example.com/content/index.html" /> </span>
```

Comment: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_substring-after-last.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use tokenize and substring-before in build function to achive your desired ouput:

***EXAMPLE INPUT:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <exp>www.example.com/content/index.html</exp>
</body>
```

***EXAMPLE XSLT:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="exp">
        <span transId="gadget_{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(tokenize(., '/')[last()],'.')" />
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

***EXAMPLE OUTPUT:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <span transId="gadget_2">index</span>
</body>
```